# Problem Installing the Mobile SDK for android

Tags: mobile, install

I am not able to install the Sales force mobile SDK from GIT hub, i tried to download the zip file and also run the install.vbs file, but it gives error as 'There was an error getting the status of the git repository: '' Make sure the 'git' executable is on your PATH variable.' I could not find the git executable in my folders.

Am not sure if i am missing something.

Can some suggest the steps to install the SDK as well as how to set the environment variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to **clone** the SDK from github, not just download.  So:

```
git clone git://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android.git
```

Not simply downloading the zip.  This creates a local git repo that the install script requires to use for downloading related projects.